# ASP.NET Core Project Often Fails to Load CSS in Chrome After Initial Run Without Debugging

Tags: .net

ASP.NET Core projects will often fail to refresh CSS style sheets (Bootstrap seems unaffected) in Chrome after first run without debugging session. What I've noticed...

Opening a new project and running without debugging works fine until you start changing the CSS and then eventually the changes stop being minified in the rebuilds and stop being sent to the browser

Once a project breaks (it runs, just the CSS doesn't get sent), even closing and reopening the project doesn't fix the CSS refresh problem

Behavior is inconsisent, sometimes you can make 2 or 3 sets of changes and everything works fine, but then the next change breaks and no changes thereafter get minified or sent to the browser

Solution appears to be to clear Chrome's cache, not an ideal workflow

I figured this out because my CSS changes weren't working in Chrome, so I tried Edge and the changes were working. So I went back to Chrome, cleared the cache, and everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

You you using `app-append-version` to take care of caching for js and css files

eg:

`<link href="~/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
<script src="~/js/app.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>`

This can help solve this issues in both dev and production.